# How to avoid page break in latex when a new section is created after the previous subsection?

Tags: latex, page-break

I am working on latex document. My packages are

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
```

Everything is fine but when the first subsection is completed and I use the next section command `\section{blah blah}`, it starts on a new page. I have abundant space in the same page and hence I don't want the page break. I even used `\nopagebreak` command and it's still the same. Please help!

Comment: You do know you've set `\sectionbreak` to be a `\clearpage`. That necessarily ejects the current page, moving on to the top of the following page... right?

Comment: This question fits on [Tex.SE].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

command and use \pagebreak where ever required. That satisfies your requirement. Hope it helps!